# Prolog. Construct a transitive closure of a graph

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I'm very new to Prolog.
I have such a graph:

```
edge(a,e).
edge(e,f).
edge(f,d).
edge(d,a).
```

I define a transitive closure as:

```
p(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
tran(X,Z) :- p(X,Y), p(Y,Z).
```

I need to construct a transitive closure of a graph. Please let me know how to proceed with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to express "ancestor" recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048419/how-to-express-ancestor-recursively)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `trans/2` is that it will only walk *two* edges, not an arbitrary number.

We can define a predicate `tran(X, Z)` that holds if `edge(X, Z)` holds, or `edge(X, Y)` and then `tran(Y, Z)`. We thus in the latter follow one edge and then recurse on `tran/2`:

```
tran(X, Z) :-
    edge(X, Z).
tran(X, Z) :-
    edge(X, Y),
    tran(Y, Z).
```

Comment: How do I add edges that satisfy a condition to a graph?

Comment: @willemvanonsem - what about loops? Your program might loop forever. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258188/prolog-eliminating-cycles-from-indirect-relation

Comment: @peak: in that case you add an accomulator: a list with items already seen.